# NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification returns empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I have a issue with use CoreData + iCloud sync.

Sometimes, the notification, NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, returns a empty array in Inserted, Updated and Deleted.

If this notification is called when have changes, why return a empty notification?

Thanks!!!

Code that calls the Notification:

```
 - (void)persistentStoreDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
 {
     DLog(@"Change Detected! Notification: %@", notification.description)

     [__managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^(void)
     {
         [__managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

         for(id<CoreDataDelegate>delegate in _delegates)
         {
             if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(persistentStoreDidChange)])
                [delegate persistentStoreDidChange];

         }
     }];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It just does that sometimes. It's a pretty minor issue compared to the many severe problems of iCloud with Core Data.

What I like to do when receiving this notification is to check for inserted, updated, and deleted objects first, and then don't go ahead with the merge process unless you find something. Do something like

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
if (([userInfo objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey] > 0) || 
    ([userInfo objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey] > 0) || 
    ([userInfo objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey] > 0)) 
{
    // merge...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But why sometimes data are corrupted? I observed that when the app save more times (MOC save), and the same objects in many devices at same time, the data to be corrupted... If the app limits the number of MOC save, do you think that the sync runs fine?

Comment: Hard to say without more detail. If you save the same objects on multiple devices at the same time, you'll get a conflict. That conflict might not be resolved the way you expect it to be resolved. If that's the kind of "corruption" you're seeing, that's just how it works. If not, post a new question with more detail about what you're seeing.